# is there any Algorithm to allocate continuous 3 seats in flight while having some booked seats?

Tags: algorithm

I would like to go through good Algorithm to allocate continuous 3 seats in flight while having some booked seats.

**Basically I want to find no of possible 3 continuos free seats to book?**

I have tried to go through greedy way where i check continuous 3 unbooked seats and then count total no of seats to allocate 3 continuous seats.

Comment: what exactly do you want to search? the amount of three sequential free seats or (based on a given booked seat) the next tree continious free seats?

Comment: @Radinator : Yes I wanted to find total possible 3 free contentious seats to allocate, edited the question as well

Comment: i would iterate through all elements , test every second seat. if it is a free seat on index n, test if seat `n-1` and `n+1` are free. Or iterate, test if seat `n`, `n+1` and `n+2` are free.

Comment: @Radinator : You are correct, I am doing the same thing but is there any standard algorithm, if yes then i would like to learn that.

Answer (score 6):

```
//n - number of rows, s- occupied seats
 `public int getAvailableSeats(int n, String s) {
    String str[] = s.split(" ");
    List<String> occupied = new ArrayList<>();
    int available = 0;

    occupied = Arrays.asList(str);

    for(int i = 1; i<= n ; i++) {

            if(!occupied.contains(i+"A") && !occupied.contains(i+"B") && !occupied.contains(i+"C")) {
                available++;
            }
            if(!(occupied.contains(i+"D") && occupied.contains(i+"G"))  && !(occupied.contains(i+"E") || occupied.contains(i+"F"))) {
                available++;
            }
            if(!occupied.contains(i+"H") && !occupied.contains(i+"J") && !occupied.contains(i+"K")) {
                available++;
            }
   }
    return available;
    }`
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: The code is self explanatory with good naming and straightforward logic, no need for further explanation

Answer (score 3):

**My Interpretation of your question:**

You have N seats in a row. There are K seats (1-indexed) that have been already booked. Find the number of contiguous segments of 3 seats where none have already been booked.

**O(K log K) Solution:**

Let the booked seats (in order) be B1, B2 ... Bk. Store the a sorted list of the following elements:

```
[0,B1,B2,...,Bk,N+1]
```

For each segement of free seats (all seats between 2 booked seats are free), the number of ways to have a contiguous segment of 3 seats is `max(0,S-2)` where S is the number of free seats in that segement.

For example, there are 10 seats and seats 3 and 9 are occupied.

The list would contain: `[0,3,9,11]`.

The first segment would have `3-0-1 = 2` free seats. Thus max(0,2-2) is 0.

The second segment would have `9-3-1 = 5` free seats. Thus max(0,5-2) is 3.

The third segement would have `11-9-1 = 1` free seat. Thus max(0,1-2) is 0.

Thus there are exactly 3 ways to have 3 contiguous segments of 3 seats.

The complexity here is `O(K log K)` as there are `K` elements to sort in `K log K` time and each of the `K+1` segments take `O(1)` time to compute. This is more feasible if N is very large (billions) and K is smaller (~100000).

**O(N) Solution**

Check every 3 seats if it all are free. This is feasible if K is larger (millions) and N is smaller (of course still more than or equal to K)

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of **O(K log K) Solution** from @Benson Lin in Python.

```py
def solution(N: int, S: str, n: int) -> int:
    """
    return option count
    """
    taken = [[] for _ in range(N)]
    for s in S.split(" "):
        row = int(s[:-1]) - 1
        if row > N:
            raise Exception("illegal reservation")

        taken[row].append(ord(s[-1]) - ord('A'))

    total_cnt = 0
    for row in taken:
        row.sort()
        row.append(ord('K') - ord('A') + 1)
        last = -1

        cnt = 0
        for idx in range(len(row)):
            free_seats = row[idx] - last - 1
            cnt += max(0, free_seats - (n - 1))
            last = row[idx]

        total_cnt += cnt

    return total_cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("countFamilySeats" + familySeats(1, "1D 4C 5E"));
        
    }
    public static  int familySeats(int planeRows,String occupiedSeats){
            Map<Integer, String> seatMap = new HashMap<>();
            int countFamilySeats = 0;
        if (occupiedSeats == null || occupiedSeats.isEmpty()) {
            return planeRows * 3;
        }
          //for the Aisles : i have mentioned Z character
        for (int i = 1; i <= planeRows; i++) {
            String myData = new String("ABCZDEFGZHJK");
            seatMap.put(i, myData);
        }
        String[] occupiedSeatsArray = occupiedSeats.split(" ");
        
        System.out.println(seatMap.size());
        // int i=0;
        for (String occupied : occupiedSeatsArray) {
            char seatRow = occupied.charAt(0);
            char seatName = occupied.charAt(1);
            int row = Character.getNumericValue(seatRow);
            String seatNameCurrent = seatMap.get(row);

            String newSeatName = seatNameCurrent != null ? seatNameCurrent.replace(seatName, 'X') : null;
            System.out.println("Updating : " +newSeatName + " for row " + row);
            seatMap.put(row, newSeatName);
        }

        // AB?|DE?F|HJK
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : seatMap.entrySet()) {
            
            String seatMapWithOccupiedData = entry.getValue();
            
            if (seatMapWithOccupiedData!=null && seatMapWithOccupiedData.contains("X")) {
                String[] tempSeatName = entry.getValue().split("X");
                for (String combinedSeats : tempSeatName) {
                    if (combinedSeats.length() <= 3) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("X is found : " + combinedSeats);
                    if (combinedSeats.length() >= 3 && !combinedSeats.contains("Z")) {
                        countFamilySeats++;
                    } else if (combinedSeats.length() >= 3 && combinedSeats.contains("Z")) {
                        String[] temp = combinedSeats.split("Z");
                        System.out.println(temp.length);
                        for (String t1 : temp) {
                            System.out.println("AISLE Separation " + t1);
                            if (t1.length() >= 3)
                                countFamilySeats++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This portion is not suitable for family" + combinedSeats);
                    }

                }
            } else {
                countFamilySeats += 3;
            }

            System.out.println(" Till this row :"+entry.getKey()+"  family seats allowed :  " + countFamilySeats);
            
        }
        

    enter code here
        return countFamilySeats;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did similar task in Codility for the hiring test. I did it using bit arithmetics.
Occupied seat map for one row of seats can be encoded as bit mask, ex: 0b1001000011, where 1 means occupied seat
then I fill the hash map of all occupied seats (rowNum -> occupied seat map for the row)

to test against seats, bitwise OR used:  test occupied OR required_mask == required_mask ,
where required mask is encoded pattern for continuous seating (ex: 0001111000, or 001100000) . For the given N rows, complexity will be O(N) , assuming that number of options for continius seat allocation per row is limited (biggest plane A380 has 10 seats in a row separated by two isles, so all continuous combinations can be encoded as bit masks)